# Updates to DocumentRoot in httpd.conf do not update in phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, localhost

My localhost was working without issue when I tried to follow this guide (https://davidsword.ca/development/setting-up-localhost-apachephp-on-icloud-drive/#comment-1974) to set iCloud as the localhost folder instead of /User/myusername/Sites. To be safe I copied the httpd.conf and username.conf files just in case. I didn't get iCloud working as localhost so deleted the updated httpd.conf and username.conf files and reverted to old ones. 
Since then I can only get onto my localhost via http://localhost/~myusername/ and get a 403 error when accessing http://http://localhost (which always worked previously)
The phpinfo file is still showing the DOCUMENT_ROOT to be the iCloud one from the guide, even though in the httpd.conf file it shows the following:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/"

<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">

    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've restarted Apache and the macbook several times but it won't update. Is there somewhere else this is stored or a cache of something I can clear to force it to update?

I understand I can set up a virtual host to work around this but I'd rather update the documentroot if possible - thanks

Comment: restart the server

Comment: I've restarted several times already, it does not update. I use sudo apachectl restart

Comment: `apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` returns?

Comment: did you follow this too? https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Comment: apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE returns 
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

Comment: coolestguide was what I originally followed to set up my localhost as /Users/myusername/Sites and activate PHP, install mysql etc